# AWS CodeDeploy not working in private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-vpc

I have private Subnet inside VPC, with a routing table as follows:

```
XX.X.0.X/16 local
0.0.0.0/0 nat-0XXXXXXXXX
```

With above configuration AWS CodeDeploy fails with error as `Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS` with no log entry in `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`.

But when I change it to allow public access by adding Internet Gateway
with following routing table AWS CodeDeploy gets successfully compeleted.

```
XX.X.0.X/16 local   
0.0.0.0/0 igw-0XXXXXXXXX
```

Am I missing any other configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CodeDeploy agent requires outbound access to the internet for access to 4 different service endpoints. Access to all these endpoints are required in order for the service to work properly.

Outbound access to the internet is needed to access to **(1)** the [CodeDeploy service endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#codedeploy_region), and **(2)** to access S3 or Github services - this access is required to the agent to download software deployment package for the revision being deployed.

From [CodeDeploy FAQs:](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/faqs/)

> ...AWS CodeDeploy agent installed on the Amazon EC2 instances must be
>   able to access the public AWS CodeDeploy and Amazon S3 service
>   endpoints. For more information, see AWS CodeDeploy Endpoints and
>   Amazon S3 Endpoints.

**(3)** The CodeDeploy agent will regularly [check for software updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-update.html), and automatically update itself within 24 hours of a new release. A properly configured CodeDeploy agent instance will allow IAM S3 access to the [AWS CodeDeploy Resource Kit Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/resource-kit.html) bucket, so that it can access new software when available. Failure to provide update access here could break your implementation when the service is upgraded, or limit access to new features.

**(4)** Regarding CodeDeploy command and control, the source code for the agent shows a reference to a special command `https` endpoint, called the `AWS_DEPLOY_CONTROL_ENDPOINT`:

From aws-codedeploy-agent software [repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/29d4ff4797c544565ccae30fd490aeebc9662a78/vendor/gems/codedeploy-commands-1.0.0/lib/aws/plugins/deploy_control_endpoint.rb#L9), the `deploy_control_endpoint.rb` file has the following:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

module Aws
  module Plugins
    class DeployControlEndpoint < Seahorse::Client::Plugin
      option(:endpoint) do |cfg|
        url = ENV['AWS_DEPLOY_CONTROL_ENDPOINT']
        if url.nil?
          url = "https://codedeploy-commands.#{cfg.region}.amazonaws.com"
          if "cn" == cfg.region.split("-")[0]
            url.concat(".cn")
          end
        end
        url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

While apparently not documented, access to this endpoint is also required.

Comment: Thanks for answer.My issue is resolved when I configured NAT gateway to allow instances to communicate to outside network.